# square system of polynomial equations having infinite number of solutions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, polynomials

Suppose we have a system of $n$ polynomial equations in $n$ unknowns over $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that the corresponding ideal generated by these equations is not the unit ideal $(1)$. Under what conditions will the system have infinite number of solutions? One obvious condition is when these equations are algebraically dependent. Are there conditions other than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I\subset \mathbb{C}[X_1, \cdots, X_n]$ be the ideal generated by your $n$ polynomials. Then a corollary of the Nullstellensatz says that $V(I)$ is a finite set if and only if $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\cdots, X_n]/I$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}.$ If that occurs, then $| V(I) | \leq \dim_k ( \mathbb{C}[X_1,\cdots, X_n]/I ).$

So your system will have an infinite number of solutions if and only if $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\cdots, X_n]/I$ is infinite dimensional as a complex vector space.